# Unable to start SQL Server 2017 container with persisted data from Docker Desktop

Tags: sql-server, containers, docker-desktop

I'm unable to start SQL Server 2017 container from Docker Desktop. Here's the code I use:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=ThisIsAPassword123@#$" `
-p 1433:1433 --name mySQLcontainer `
-d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest -v sqlvol:/var/opt/mssql/data
```

I use this command to get the log:

```
 docker logs mySQLcontainer
```

This is the exception I see:

```
docker : /opt/mssql/bin/nonroot_msg.sh: line 59: exec: -v: invalid option
```

It looks like something to do with permissions. Since, when I run the same command without the volume (**-v sqlvol:/var/opt/mssql/data**) it works fine.

I really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: What does `docker volume inspect sqlvol` tell you?

Comment: Thank you @AlwaysLearning

This problem got fixed, after rebooting the machine. I wish it had stayed to give me an opportunity to troubleshoot. I'll leave my post; in case, i face it again.